# Multiple blobs to single zip file with JSzip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jszip

i try to download multiple images with single ZIP  file but i get the opposite. Which is to download zip files but they come in separated zip files .
And when i console log the `urls[]` array they come in different arrays .

```js
const fileURLs = window.URL.createObjectURL(result);// that is blob 
var zip = new JSZip();
var count = 0;
var zipFilename = "Selective.zip";
var urls = [ // i try to make them array 
fileURLs 
];

console.log(urls);

  urls.forEach(function(url){
  var filename = result.name;
  // loading a file and add it in a zip file
  JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
     if(err) {
        throw err; // or handle the error
     }
     zip.file(filename, data, {binary:true});
     count++;
       zip.generateAsync({type:'blob'}).then(function(content) {
          saveAs(content, zipFilename);
       });

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need wait for all the blob write to the zip.

```
if(count === urls.length) {
  zip.generateAsync({type:'blob'}).then(function(content) {
     saveAs(content, zipFilename);
  });
}
```